# Action Creator is undefined in this.props

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I have a redux code that used to work but now throws "this.props.watchSlidesData" is not a function error.  this.props.watchSlidesData is undefined in this.props.watchSlidesData()" when calling this.props.watchSlidesData(); in ComponentWillMount ().

I have ensured that all variables defined are correctly spelled in reducers, actions, types, mapToDispatchProps and mapToStateProps and wired correctly with connect.  Necessary imports (e.g. connect and watchSlidesData ) are also done in the calling component (in this case WelcomeScreen.js). See code snippets below.

Some code snippets:

```
//action (index.js)

import firebase from 'firebase';


import { 
    SLIDES_CHANGED,
} from './types';

export const watchSlidesData = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    firebase.database().ref("slides")
    .on("value", snapshot => 
    { 
        dispatch({ 
          type: SLIDES_CHANGED,
          payload: snapshot.val() });
    }, function(error) { console.log(error); });
  }
};

// WelcomeScreen.js snippet

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { watchSlidesData } from '../store/actions/';

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.watchSlidesData();
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ appdata }) => {
  const {  slidesData } = appdata;
  return { 
    slidesData: slidesData,
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { 
    watchSlidesData: () => dispatch(watchSlidesData()),
    // actions: bindActionCreators({ watchSlidesData }, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(WelcomeScreen);
```

I expect photos to be fetched from firebase and displayed as a slideshow on the WelcomeScreen. Calling the this.props.watchSlidesData() action creator in ComponentWillMount() should initiate that fetch via a dispatch. But I am getting the error (red screen):  this.props.watchSlidesData not a function and this.props.watchSlidesData is undefined

Comment: could you post a console log of your appData and slidesData?

Comment: appdata": Object {
    "slidesData": Array [
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002953/morgancares/bg0.png'",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002954/morgancares/bg3.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002953/morgancares/current-students.jpg",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002953/morgancares/bg4.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002954/morgancares/graduation2019.png",
     
    ],

Comment: My render code:

Comment: const { slidesData } = this.props;
    console.log(slidesData); // this line returns an empty array, why?
    let photos = [];
    for ( let i=0; i < slidesData.length; i++){
      photos.push(
        <Image
          style={styles.contentImageStyle}
          source={{uri: slidesData[i]}}
          key={"row-" + i}
        />
      )
    }

Comment: not in the comment, please do it in the original post, and format the console.log as code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
// WelcomeScreen.js snippet

import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { watchSlidesData } from '../store/actions/';

componentWillMount(){
    this.props.watchSlidesData();
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ appdata }) => {
  const {  slidesData } = appdata;
  return { slidesData };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps,{watchSlidesData})(WelcomeScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion; but it didn't work. The problem is with the action creator watchSlidesData() not been seen as defined and/or dispatched.  I even tried console.log (actions) but nothing referencing this action creator in the output at all. I then tried console.log(this.props) and still nothing containing these redux props. Please need help

Comment: I solved the above issue by removing the export keyword from the class (which I forgot when I changed the code to use redux) so had 2 exports in same component leading to not finding the this.props.watchSlidesData(). But now I have a new problem. the mapped state to props var (slidesData) shows the array data fetched from firebase correctly. But when I try to access the data for display, it is showing an empty array via console.log(this.props.slidesData) and thus the slide photos are not shown. Any thoughts? thx

Comment: ```const { slidesData } = this.props;
    console.log(slidesData); // this line returns an empty array, why?
    let photos = [];
    for ( let i=0; i < slidesData.length; i++){
      photos.push(
        <Image
          style={styles.contentImageStyle}
          source={{uri: slidesData[i]}}
          key={"row-" + i}
        />
      )
    }```

Comment: appdata": Object {
    "slidesData": Array [
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002953/morgancares/bg0.png'",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002954/morgancares/bg3.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002953/morgancares/current-students.jpg",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002953/morgancares/bg4.png",
      "https://res.cloudinary.com/obisi7/image/upload/v1559002954/morgancares/graduation2019.png",
    ],

Comment: console.log(slidesData) returns: Object {} and hence no data to populate photos[] and display same in app. Strange. What am I doing wrong to use the fetched data in my app via the prop object?